# Illegal string offset ' ' Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
  $jawaban =implode(' ',$request->input('pilihan'));
            $id_soal=implode(' ',$request->input('id_soal'));

            for($i=0;$i<=$jumlah_soal;$i++){
                $nomor =$id_soal[$i];
                $kunci = $jawaban[$nomor];
            if ( DB::table('tryout')->where('id_soal','=',$nomor)
                                    ->where('kunci','=',$kunci)
                                    ->first()){
                $benar++;
            }
```

I got error " Illegal string offset ' ' "

what must i do ?

Comment: which line produces this error?

Comment: $kunci = $jawaban[$nomor];

Comment: Change `$nomor =(int)$id_soal[$i];` and  `$kunci = (int)$jawaban[$nomor]; `

Comment: are `$request->input('pilihan')` and `$request->input('id_soal')` both array?? and do you understand what implode function does??

Comment: Thanks you for helping , now solved , I'm new in laravel so i don't understand about few function in laravel

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing contents of `$jawaban` as an array, but it actually is a string, because you:

```
$jawaban = implode(' ',$request->input('pilihan'));
```

even `$request->input('pilihan')` possibly is not an array also....